# How do I determine the value of x that sets a given range to a function?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I had a question on my calculus test which said:
Let $ f(x) $ be a function that is defined by the relation $\frac{3x+2}{x-1}$.

I was able to do all the sub-questions related to it except for one. The question stated that for a number $A$, where $x>A$, $f(x)$ must have the range $]2.9,3.1[$.

How do I determine the possible values of the real number $A$?

From the graph, I can approximate that when $x>52$, $f(x)$ starts to fall into the given range, but how do I prove this mathematically?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that the function values approach $3$ as $x\to \infty$. This question is asking when we get close. Let's solve the equations $f(x)=2.9$ and $f(x)=3.1$

$$\frac{3x+2}{x-1}=2.9\implies x=-49$$

and

$$\frac{3x+2}{x-1}=3.1\implies x=51$$

Outside of those bounds, i.e., when $x<-49$ and when $x>51$, your desired inequality should be satisfied. Because of the way your question is phrased ("find $A$ such that when $x>A$...."), we can just use the $x>51$ condition.

---

One way to get a better sense of what's going on is to rewrite the function this way (using polynomial long division, if necessary):

$$f(x)=3+\frac{5}{x-1}$$

Looking at it this way, you can see that the question is really asking, when is $\left|\frac{5}{x-1}\right|<\frac{1}{10}$?

Comment: G Tony - What is standard way of handling such questions? I mean which are discontinuous at some middle point. While this is obvious from graph, its not so for me without it. Thanks and +1!

Comment: Well, functions come in a great variety of shapes and flavors. It helps to have a sense of what we're working with, which I would usually obtain by looking at a sketch of a graph. For example, just to cook up a messy one: $f(x)=(3x^2+3x-35)/(x^2-9)$. This also approaches $3$ at either end, but we also have $f(8/3)=3$. Therefore, $f$ gets close to $3$ both "near infinity", and also near $\frac83$. These need to be dealt with individually. This function has discontinuities (vertical asymptotes) at $x=\pm 3$, so we expect three distinct pieces of domain, each with its own.... features.

Comment: There's something algebraic that can help, too; I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, last edit is particularly very useful here!

Comment: Thank you, @GTonyJacobs, this clarified the idea. This made me think of using the definition of a limit to get the result as well:
$lim f(x)$ as $x \to \infty$ = 3.
Using the definition of the limit:
$$|f(x) - L| < δ$$
$$L = \frac{2.9+3.1}{2}=3$$
$$δ = \frac{3.1-2.9}{2}=0.1$$
The condition of the question is satisfied when $$|f(x) - 3| < 0.1$$
$$|\frac{3x+2}{x-1} - 3| < \frac{1}{10}$$
$$\left|\frac{5}{x-1}\right|<\frac{1}{10}$$
Because $x \to \infty$
$$\frac{5}{x-1}<\frac{1}{10}$$
Therefore, $x > 51$.

Comment: Yes, that's an excellent approach!

Answer (score 1):

Note that the function is decreasing (the derivative is $\frac{-5}{(x-1)^2}$) and has a limiting value of $3$ as $x$ approaches $+\infty$. So we can choose $A$ such that $f(A) = 3.1$. This is relatively easy to solve for $A$ -- see G Tony Jacobs's answer, where he does this and gets $A = 51$.

Comment: Probably want to deal with both ends of the domain...

Comment: @GTonyJacobs The question asked for $A$ such that when $x > A$, $f(x)$ falls in the desired range. If $A < 2$ this obviously can't work (take $x=2$ for example, then $x > A$ but $f(x)$ is outside of the domain), so $A > 2$ and thus only the right side of the domain matters here.

Comment: Oops, you're right! Missed that detail :)